# Socket.io Online users count

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I created a chat site using socket.io, node.js, nginx. But there is a problem with the number of online users. As soon as a new Internet tab is opened, a new user is added to the number of online users. If I open 10 new tabs, 10 new online users arrive. It is necessary that user count is unique IP amount! Thank you!

Connected

```
io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
  // push current user in sockets
  sockets.push(socket);

  // get all users
  const allSockets = await io.allSockets();

  // emit the size of allSockets
  io.emit("numberOfOnline", allSockets.size);
```

Disconnected

```
    // remove the current user in sockets, searching, and notAvailable array if the user disconnects
    sockets = sockets.filter((user) => user.id !== socket.id);
    searching = searching.filter((user) => user.id !== socket.id);
    notAvailable = notAvailable.filter((user) => user.id !== socket.id);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", async () => {
    // get all users
    const allSockets = await io.allSockets();

    // emit the size of allSockets
    io.emit("numberOfOnline", allSockets.size);
  });
```

Comment: So what do you want, allow only 1 user per 1 IP or count unique IP amount?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I need count unique IP amount.

Answer (score 0):

If inside your `sockets` array contains only actual connections you can try this code

```
const ips = new Set();
sockets.map(item=>ips.add(item.request.connection.remoteAddress));

console.log(ips.size);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but no, still counting actual connections.

Comment: Could you `console.log(ips, ips.size)` ?

Comment: Still nothing. App is crashing by adding this code.

Comment: What version of socket.io? could you `console.log(sockets)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is error log

```
2021-02-12T20:58:16.084895+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2021-02-12T20:58:16.084962+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the socketiopractice@1.0.0 start script.
2021-02-12T20:58:16.085040+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-02-12T20:58:16.092404+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-02-12T20:58:16.092658+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-02-12T20:58:16.092791+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-02-12T20_58_16_085Z-debug.log
2021-02-12T20:58:16.163256+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-12T20:58:16.271729+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-12T20:58:17.036652+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=3b2edd32-47b7-4549-a8df-3f80cab096f5 fwd="46.109.220.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-12T20:58:43.051339+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=app.herokuapp.com request_id=8955b076-bf77-4003-ac86-a18d27e3300a fwd="46.109.220.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```